# Duplicate list items using list comprehension

Tags: python

I would like to duplicate the items of a list into a new list, for example

```
a=[1,2]
b=[[i,i] for i in a]
```

gives `[[1, 1], [2, 2]]`, whereas I would like to have `[1, 1, 2, 2]`.

I also found that I could use:

```
b=[i for i in a for j in a]
```

but it seemed like overkill to use two `for` loops. Is it possible to do this using a single `for` loop?

Comment: Do you want to repeat each item **2** times or `len(a)` times?

Comment: Note that these are not just `for` loops, they are [list comprehensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw). It's worth knowing the mechanics of how they work, not least because there are a number of sibling constructs (generator expressions, set comprehensions, etc...) that have different behaviour.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I want to repeat each item 2 times, so `[1,2,3]` would become `[1,1,2,2,3,3]`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Then your list comprehension based code is actually wrong.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks, I realized that now.

Comment: Zip the list to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), which takes an iterable of iterables and returns a single iterable with all the elements of the sub-iterables (flattening by one level):

```
b = itertools.chain.from_iterable((i, i) for i in a)
```

Combined with a generator expression, you get the result you want. Obviously, if you *need* a list, just call `list()` on the iterator, but in most cases that isn't needed (and is less efficient).

If, as Ashwini suggests, you want each item `len(a)` times, it's simple to do that as well:

```
duplicates = len(a)
b = itertools.chain.from_iterable([i] * duplicates for i in a)
```

Note that any of these solutions do not copy `i`, they give you multiple references to the same element. Most of the time, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your two-loop code does not actually do what you want, because the inner loop is evaluated for every step of the outer loop. Here is an easy solution:

```
b = [j for i in a for j in (i, i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xrange` and using a generator expression or a list comprehension

```
b = (x for x in a for _ in xrange(2))

b = [x for x in a for _ in xrange(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not mind the order:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a * 2

[1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: what is wrong with the answer ? doesnt not duplicate the items of the list as the OP is asking ?

Comment: This definitely doesn't deserve a downvote - it may not be suitable for the OP's case, but it's a potential solution. The OP never said for sure order was required, and your answer notes that the order won't be as given. This is a good answer for cases where someone doesn't care - which may well be the case if someone comes to this question.